# Can the Linux find -iname option take more the one pattern

Tags: find, options

Using the Linux `find` command `-iname` option, I want to find and move files that have many different extensions (`.pdf, .doc, .xlx, .ppt`).  I know  I can use multiple patterns with `grep`.  But can that also be done with `find`?

Comment: Note that Linux is just a kernel, it doesn't have a `find` command. There are quite a few `find` implementations that have been ported to Linux and are commonly found on distributions of software built for the Linux kernel like GNU `find`, busybox `find`, etc.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - for clarification, I am referring to the Linux Bash Shell `find` command on Red Hat Linux 7.x that resides in `/bin` (i.e. `/bin/find`)

Comment: That would be GNU `find`. Most general purpose distributions of software built for the Linux kernal are generally built  upon the GNU operating system (which some people confuse with *Linux*). RedHat is now one of the biggest corporate contributors to the GNU project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not with `-iname` alone. `find` itself has an "OR":

```
   expr1 -o expr2
          Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
```

So you could do:

```
find /path/to/dir -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*.doc' -o -iname '*.xlx' -o -iname '*.ppt'
```

Beware that if you need to perform some action on either of those matching files (like `-exec`, `-print`), or add extra filtering that applies to *all* (like `-type f`), or in other words if you need to match on either of those **and** to do/check something else, since in `find` like in many other languages *and* has higher precedence than *or*, you'd need to use parentheses:

```
find /path/to/dir '(' -iname '*.pdf' \
                      -o -iname '*.doc' \
                      -o -iname '*.xlx' \
                      -o -iname '*.ppt' \
                  ')' -type f -exec ls -ld {} +
```